# I made a for loop to swap two indiv char variables in a string

Tags: java, string, random, char, swap

I am supposed to write a method that scrambles a word, switching two letters in a word that is not the first or last character.

I've initialized i and j as random integers between positions 1 and str.length() -1. Is there a reason why this loop would not print the scrambled version of a word?

```
char[] chararray = word.toCharArray();
int i = (int) (Math.random() * ((word.length()-2) - (1)) + 1); 
int j = (int) (Math.random() * ((word.length()-2) - (1)) + 1); 
for (int x = 0; x < word.length(); x++) 
    {
        if (x == i) 
        {
             chararray[x] = word.charAt(i);
        }
        else if (x == j)
        {
            chararray[x] = word.charAt(j);
        }
    }

  word = new String (chararray);
  System.out.println(word);
```

When I input `tofu` it would reprint `tofu`. I'd like to input "tofu" and have it output "tfou".

Comment: What does it print? Can you show us the complete code? Would like to see how you initialize chararray, i and j

Comment: I believe you need to show us input string, also both actual and expected output.

Comment: @Gosu what do you mean if i == j?

Comment: public static String scramble(String word)
   {
      char[] chararray = word.toCharArray()
    
      int i = (int) (Math.random() * ((word.length()-2) - (1)) + 1);
     
      int j = (int) (Math.random() * ((word.length()-2) - (1)) + 1);
    
      for (int x = 0; x < word.length(); x++) 
      {
         if (x == i) 
         {
             chararray[x] = word.charAt(i);
         }
         else if (x == j)
         {
            chararray[x] = word.charAt(j);
         }
      }
      
      word = new String (chararray);
      System.out.println(word);

Comment: I am supposed to be writing a method. @alexroussos

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am supposed to be scrambling, switching to letters in a word that is not the first or last character.

Comment: Actual output is if I input "tofu" it would reprint "tofu"

Comment: I'd like to input "tofu" and have it output "tfou"

Comment: so i and j are swapping position ??

Comment: @AnnaPolkinghorn Take a look (or even try out) my answer. I assume that is what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would be looking for the following

```
 for (int x = 0; x < word.length(); x++) 
    {
        if (x == i) 
        {
             chararray[x] = word.charAt(j);
        }
        else if (x == j)
        {
            chararray[x] = word.charAt(i);
        }
    }
```

Interchange the i and j values in the if and else blocks.

when x equals i you are assigning the same value back in the chararray, hence you are getting the same value.  But your intention is to interchange the character in i and j positions I hope.

And one more thing, make sure i never equals to j

Comment: @HJK Why do you even need a for loop?

Comment: @Gosu I was using a for loop because my cousin who is a comp sci major had told me too. I am only a beginner at this stuff

Comment: @AnnaPolkinghorn Well, you should ask him/her why do you need a for loop when you are simply swapping characters at 2 random positions. At the same time, I have no idea why all the other answers 'encourage' the use of a for loop either.

Comment: @Gosu, ideally loop is not required to interchange the characters at 2 random positions.  I just highlighted the mistake in the code keeping the semantics as is.

Answer (score 0):

Start with an character array.
Use a random generator to get 2 integers between 0 (inclusive) and length of character array (exclusive).

If **`i != j`**, swap them. (No point swapping a character with itself)

```
public class QuickTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random rand = new Random();

        char[] charArr = "elephant".toCharArray();

        // Using charArr.length - 2 + 1 to exclude first and last
        int i = rand.nextInt(charArr.length - 2) + 1;
        int j = rand.nextInt(charArr.length - 2) + 1;

        if (i != j) {
            System.out.printf("Going to swap %c at position %d "
                    + "with %c at position %d%n", charArr[i], i, charArr[j], j);

            char temp = charArr[i];
            charArr[i] = charArr[j];
            charArr[j] = temp;

            System.out.println("\nResult: " + new String(charArr));
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
Going to swap t at position 7 with e at position 2

Result: eltphane
```

**Update:**

Changed from `charArr.length` to `charArr.length - 2 + 1` to exclude first and last character.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems to be wrong,

```
 if (x == i) 
        {
             chararray[x] = word.charAt(i);
        }
```

The above will just point to same index, both x and i points to same, you need to interchange the indexes.

**Below code**

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        String word = "ankur";
        char[] chararray = word.toCharArray();
        int i = (int) (Math.random() * ((word.length() - 2) - (1)) + 1);
        int j = (int) (Math.random() * ((word.length() - 2) - (1)) + 1);
        System.out.println(i + " and " + j);
        for (int x = 0 ; x < word.length() ; x++) {
            if (x == i) {
                chararray[x] = word.charAt(j);
            } else if (x == j) {
                chararray[x] = word.charAt(i);
            }
        }

        word = new String(chararray);
        System.out.println(word);
    }
```

**output**

```
2 and 1
aknur
```

Comment: Why is there a need for a for loop?